# Schema.org/MedicalWebPage - What is proper use for specialty identification?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, medical

I am trying to add schema.org markup to a chiropractic website. My issue is how to determine which markup to use so our site will show more helpful SERPs when patients are looking for information regarding symptoms/treatment.

Our website manager has a bunch of crazy HTML and I'm plugging in the schema markup I want within existing code. Do you have to use the `<body>` tags or can the `itemscope` and `itemtype` show in `<p>` tags?

I'd like to use this markup for the page describing prenatal chiropractic care:

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MedicalWebPage">
<link itemprop="audience" href="http://schema.org/Patient"/>
<link itemprop="specialty" href="http://schema.org/Obstetric"/>
```

Is this the best way to implement the markup? I didn't see a specialty for chiropractic or I would have put it there instead of Obstetric.

Comment: Sorry, some of my question disappeared. I meant to ask Do you have to use the < body > tags or can the itemscope and itemtype show in < p >
tags?

Comment: You have to use inline code markup for this (enclose it in ` characters). I edited it for you.

Comment: In HTML, the link tag has no closing slash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google's Structured Data Testing Tool in order to validate your schema markup:

https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

I always work off the basis that if the actual value for a schema tag can be represented on the screen (ie not hidden in a tag), I'll show it. If I absolutely must include some data and can't display it on the screen I tend to use the `meta` tag, primarily as that is what I always see google use during tutorials.

To answer your question more directly; no. You can start your schema tags on whatever tags you'd like, just so long as it encompasses all of your schema markup (ie don't have an itemprop for MedicalWebPage outside of its own hierarchy).

Answer (score 0):

You schema choices are valid, you can use any tag with visible information for your markup, including `<div>`, `<body>`, `<p>`, `<span>` for things that you don't want a layout change for, and even things like `<strong>` for single properties.

`<link>` and `<meta>` are for things not visible on the page.  If you wanted to include more information about the patients you could use a `<div>` rather than `<link>` for instance. The http://schema.org/MedicalWebPage schema gives this as a helpful example which I've shortened:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MedicalWebPage">
<link itemprop="audience" href="http://schema.org/Patient" />
<link itemprop="specialty" href="http://schema.org/Cardiovascular" />
<meta itemprop="lastReviewed" content="2011-09-14"/>
<h1>About <span itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MedicalCondition"><span itemprop="name">High Blood Pressure</span></span></h1>
 ...
<h2><span itemprop="aspect">Treatment</span></h2>
There are many common treatments for high blood pressure, including
 <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/DrugClass">
  <span itemprop="name">beta-blocker</span> drugs such as propanaolol.    
  </span>
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: In HTML, the link and meta tags have no closing slash.

Comment: @Rob the schema.org examples including the closing slashes on those tags

Comment: That doesn't change what I said.